# Return a list as a column of the elements for a flask app

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, flask

My file, file.json, just has one key, 'file' that returns a list, [1,2,3,4]. 
I want to return this on the webpage:

My List

1

2

3

4

But instead I get: My List [1,2,3,4].

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import json

app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/data/')
def file():
    with open('file.json') as data:
            Data = json.load(data)
    return "My List " + str(Data['file'])
```

Comment: you have to use loop to add number one by one to string with new line .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Python's [**pretty printer library**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html) for non-response output

For rendering through jinja you can use the [**pprint**](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#pprint) filter like:

```
{{ data|pprint }}
```

OR, you can manually format the output with newlines using a variety of different strategies:

```
@app.route('/data/')
def file():
    with open('file.json') as data:
            Data = json.load(data)
    return "My List \n\n" + '\n\n'.join([str(x) for x in Data['file']])
```

Answer (score 0):

Write like that:

```
@app.route('/data/')
def file():
    with open('file.json') as data:
            Data = json.load(data)
    return 'My List <br><br>' + '<br>'.join(map(str, Data['file']))
```